# The which command is returning an error, what is an alternative?

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames

```
D1 = V1 V2 V3 V4                       
      1  2  3  4
      2  3  4  5
      3  5  4  2

D2 = V1 V2 V3
     1  2   3
     3  5   4
```

I am trying to match the two data frames and extract index of row D2 which matches with that of D1 using which but getting the error

```
which(D2[,1:3]==D1[3,1:3])


Error in Ops.data.frame : ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

(but if I write the equation separately as ,

```
 which(D2[,1]==D1[3,1] & D2[,1]==D1[3,2] & D2[,1]==D1[3,3])
```

there is no problem but I want to generalise it)
Please suggest some alternative.

Comment: Your "separate" equations are not equivalent to the original one.

Comment: When I run the separate equations it always returns `integer(0)` for me. Maybe be a difference in how the data is created. For that reason please remember to create the data in a reproducible, runnable way in your questions.

Comment: Will keep in mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
which(apply(D2, 1, function(x) all(D1[3,1:3] == x)))
```

> [1] 2

Data:

```
D1 <- read.table(text="V1 V2 V3 V4                       
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  5  4  2", header=T)

D2 <- read.table(text="V1 V2 V3
1  2   3
3  5   4", header=T)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @user2999110 Happy to help! Please check the green check mark if you don't mind